# Can't verify url certificate using wget (don't have root access)

Tags: server, certificate, ssl-certificate, wget

I am on a remote server and we don't have sudo access. I have a script which helps download data from this url: wget https://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz

Code:

```
# Download the cinic dataset
cd ../..
mkdir -p data/cinic
wget -P 'data/cinic' wget https://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz
cd data/cinic
tar -xzf CINIC-10.tar.gz
rm CINIC-10.tar.gz
```

However I get the error:

```
--2021-04-30 02:04:31--  http://wget/
Resolving wget (wget)... failed: Device or resource busy.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘wget’
--2021-04-30 02:04:31--  https://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz
Resolving datashare.is.ed.ac.uk (datashare.is.ed.ac.uk)... 129.215.41.53
Connecting to datashare.is.ed.ac.uk (datashare.is.ed.ac.uk)|129.215.41.53|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found : Moved Temporarily
Location: https://datashare.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz [following]
--2021-04-30 02:04:32--  https://datashare.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz
Resolving datashare.ed.ac.uk (datashare.ed.ac.uk)... 192.41.117.26
Connecting to datashare.ed.ac.uk (datashare.ed.ac.uk)|192.41.117.26|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify datashare.ed.ac.uk's certificate, issued by ‘CN=QuoVadis Europe EV SSL CA G1,O=QuoVadis Trustlink B.V.,C=NL’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to datashare.ed.ac.uk insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
tar (child): CINIC-10.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
rm: cannot remove 'CINIC-10.tar.gz': No such file or directory
```

Now I am not an expert in how certificates work and I read another stackoverflow post to check for certi errors and look for something called `extra download` here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=datashare.is.ed.ac.uk I don't know how to read this site but I don't see any errors.

How can I resolve certificate error and run the shell script?

Comment: datashare.is.ed.ac.uk (at least for your URL) redirects to datashare.ed.ac.uk, and it is the latter that has the error, as the error message says. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=datashare.ed.ac.uk shows 'Chain issues incomplete' and the needed 'Extra download'. https://whatsmychaincert.com/?datashare.ed.ac.uk finds it for you, or since the former site _does_ serve it you could use `openssl s_client -showcerts` on that. PS: this isn't really a programming question or problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I don't understand much of how certificates work so apologies if SO is not the right place to ask. However, if I may ask, how can one use `openssl s_clent -showcerts`. Will it be like `wget -P 'data/cinic' wget https://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz openssl s_clent -showcerts` ?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Anther question: The link inside  whatsmychaincert.com/?datashare.ed.ac.uk when clicked, shows a file to be downloaded. How can I use it as a url with `wget`?